# Create span with DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm have a table in html that looks like this

```
<table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="myTable" class="myTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><center>Day</center></th>
            <th colspan="2"><center>F</center></th>
            <th>Sunrise</th>
            <th colspan="2"><center>D</center></th>
            <th colspan="2"><center>A</center></th>
            <th colspan="2"><center>M</center></th>
            <th colspan="2"><center>I</center></th>
        </tr>

        <colgroup>

        </colgroup>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbodyid"> </tbody>

</table>
```

And then I'm adding cells using DOM like this

```
var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(xa);

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText  = document.createTextNode("hello");

// Append a text node to the cell
newCell.appendChild(newText);
```

Where xa is a counter. In the new cell I create I want to add

```
<span class="full-row">hello</span>
```

But when I replace hello with,

```
<span class="full-row">LONG text</span>
```

it prints out

```
<span class="full-row">LONG text</span>
```

Just like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the element and then set the text in it:

```
  var theSpan = document.createElement("span"); 
  //set the content of the span
  var theSpanContents = document.createTextNode("hello");
  theSpan.appendChild(theSpanContents); 
  //append the span
  newCell.appendChild(theSpan);
```

Comment: While this is absolutely fine, I'm curious as to the use of `createTextNode('hello')` (and `appendChild()`) when you could get away with `theSpan.textContent = 'hello';`?

Comment: There are several ways you could do it. In many cases setting innerHTML property is significantly faster than createElement. I don't know exactly what your use case is, so I wouldn't try to suggest how you go about it. Usually, JS performance isn't a major concern when you are just adding/removing a couple of nodes.